# What bosses am I missing for the Exterminator achievement?

Tags: achievements, terraria-console

My questions is what bosses am I missing to get the exterminator achievement?
I have beaten the following bosses on the console release version of the game:

- Eye of Cthulhu
- King Slime
- Eater of Worlds
- Skeletron
- Wall of Flesh
- Destroyer
- The Twins
- Skeletron Prime
- Ocram

Who have I not beat yet?

Answer (score 0):

Going by [this guide](http://www.trueachievements.com/a175171/exterminator-achievement.htm) (and assuming your game is up to date) for Xbox 360, you need to kill:

**Pre-Hard mode:**

- King Slime
- Eye of Cthulu
- Eater of Worlds
- Skeletron
- Wall of Flesh

**Post Hard Mode**

- The Twins
- The Destroyer
- Skeletron Prime
- Ocram
- Brain of Cthulu*
- Queen Bee*
- Plantera*
- Golem*

<sub>*part of update 1.2</sub>

---

Given the list you provided and if your game is up to date, you still need to kill:

- Golem
- Queen Bee
- Plantera
- Brain of Cthulu

If your game is not updated, check the leaderboard to see if you have a kill recorded for each boss.  The ones from the update will not be on the leaderboards however.